# Vuex Vue3 mutation on store modifies incorrect state item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex4

I am trying to commit a change to a state in the store but I am having trouble with the mutation only changing the value that I want to be changed.

Here is a sample of my state (tableMap) before the mutation:

```js
{
    "1": {
       "prop1":0,
       "prop2":0,
       "personMap":{
         "0001":{
           "choice":null
        },
    "2": {
       "prop1":0,
       "prop2":0,
       "personMap":{
         "0001":{
           "choice":null
        },
    // ...
}
```

The mutation function:

```js
updateTableMap: function (state, value) {
  const instance = value.instance; // value passed in for this example is "1"
  const personID = value.personID; // value passed in for this example is "0001"
  const choice = value.choice; // value passed in for this example is '0'
  console.log(state.tableMap) // result is top block of code
  state.tableMap[instance].personMap[personID].choice = choice;
  console.log(state.tableMap) // result is bottom block of code
  // ...
}
```

I thought that I would only be updating one value with function call. However, this is what tableMap looks like after the mutation:

```js
{
    "1": {
       "prop1":0,
       "prop2":0,
       "personMap":{
         "0001":{
           "choice": 0
        },
    "2": {
       "prop1":0,
       "prop2":0,
       "personMap":{
         "0001":{
           "choice": 0
        },
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, although I specifically define what instance I want to be mutated, somehow in both instance 1 and 2, the choice for the person with id "0001" are changed. I would like it if only the the choice for the specific instance I pass in changes. How can I do this?

Comment: there's nothing in the code shown that should cause such a result.  It's impossible to call an array with a specific index and have a different index also change.  Have you inserted any console.logs to confirm the mutation only runs once?  Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in an online sandbox or git repo?

Comment: Your `personMap` keys may refer to the same JavaScript Object - so if you change the key `choice` of that Object, the change will be visible through both of its references.

Comment: @yoduh I placed the console logs right before and right after `state.tableMap[instance].personMap[personID].choice = choice`. The code block below was the final console log

Comment: Then what @IVOGELOV said is the only thing that could possibly make sense.  The `personMap` could reference the same object in memory.  Changing one, changes the other, because they are technically the same thing.  Depending on how the tableMap state is constructed, it is possible.